# Slip joint slipping

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, repair

excuse my lack of terminology ahead of time.

I have a toilet with a slip joint. The piping came undone (wet mess). I figured looking at the washer may have been old, so I purchased a new nut/washer. I've tightened the new nut with washer but the pressure from the water system disconnects the joint.

I'm not sure what I'm missing. Here is an image of the piping disconnected from main line. I've also attached an image of how I'm attaching the nut/washer. [image: my toilet]

[image: my setup]

Comment: Does the discharge of this pipe go straight down to a commercial urinal, without any elbows?

Comment: The end of that pipe usually goes directly into the urinal fitting with no extension piece. If the piece is not long enough get the right length piece and complete the installation. The top picture shows an elbow, are you using that elbow; please explain.